# javascript comparisson is way error

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need help i have html like this

```
`<input id="from" type="text" value="0"`>
 <input id="until" type="text" value="0"`>
<a type="button" id="btnval">compare</a>
```

and on Javascript

```
$('#btnval').on('click', function() {
    var from = $('#from').val();
    var until = $('#until').val();
    console.log(from > until)
});
```

when i try from = 4 and until = 0, is show true
but when i'm input from = 12 and until = 4 is show false. why?? nuntil is less then from. I want Until mas large then from?? Or i get bug???

Comment: sorry edit, mas is must*. I'm kinda typo and my english kinda worst xD

Comment: You can edit your questions, just hit the word "edit" under your question

Comment: [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) returns a string. You have to convert the values first -> [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt/)

Answer (score 1):

In these cases you can use from parseInt() to handle values as integer value:

```
var from = parseInt($('#from').val());
```

Also there are another function parseFloat() for handle float values

Comment: @Rayon thank you for your great attention i edited my post and explained parseFloat()